# Compare two sheets in one excel workbook?

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I'm new in excel. Could any one help me in comparing the columns between two sheet on the basis of a key.

Requirement is:

1. There are 7 columns in both the sheets.
2. I've to take 7th column as key and search the key in another sheet.
3. Then on the basis of key compare 1 to 6 columns in both the sheets.

There are around 17000 records in both the excels.
It is like a key-value pair comparison.

Kindly help..

Comment: What are you expecting to see as a result of the comparison? A single value indicating whether the row is the same or different, or a cell-by-cell breakdown?

Comment: Something like:
Picked key-value from one sheet compared it within values available in another sheet. The values which are matching set true/false in a new column available in sheet1.

Comment: Because your lookup value is in the rightmost position, you can't use `VLOOKUP()` for this, as it can only look to the right. You can either move the lookup key to the left, or use `INDEX()` and `MATCH()` to mimic its behaviour - see [here](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/left-lookup.html) for info.

Answer (score 0):

You can try in the third sheet of the excel as " = EXCEL(sheet1:text,sheet2text)". Post that hit Enter. It should give you a true or False result. there you go , you compared the data in two sheets.